# Populating LocomotiveCMS select options with states?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import, html-select, locomotivecms

I am attempting my first LocomotiveCMS installation currently and this is also my first experience with Rails so the learning curve is a bit steep. I finally got my CMS installed, configured and working correctly and now I am on to adding content.

I've create two content models, each model has a select dropdown for a state selector and I was wondering how I can populate the options for the select dropdown with a list of all the States instead of manually adding all the states into the options for each model.

Please advise, thank you!

Comment: Or if you could tell me how I can copy the options from one model to another that would be fine too, I've already entered all the states into one of the models manually.

Comment: Disregard, I determined that I was using the wrong section all along. I've created a "States" model and added all 50 states manually to that model, so now I can use it as a relationship within other models.